How to use Question number instead of page number in this example?
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain, twoside]{ctexrep}
\ctexset{
    chapter    =  {
        name   =  {},
        number =  {}
    },            
    section    =  {
        name   =  {},
        number =  {}
    }
}%
\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totpages}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\tcbset{%
    colback          = white,
    colframe         = black,
    title filled     = false,
    bookmark         = {Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    number freestyle = { Q\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter} }
    ]{question}{ O{}mo }{
    fonttitle        = \bfseries,
    title            = \thetcbcounter:,
    #1
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\mytopic}[1]{%
\clearpage
    \begin{question}{Question label}
        #1  
    \end{question}
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{11}
\mytopic{\lipsum[1]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[2]}
\clearpage
\section{22}
\mytopic{\lipsum[3]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[4]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[5]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[6]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[7]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[8]}
\clearpage
\section{33}
\mytopic{\lipsum[9]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[10]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[11]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[12]}

\end{document}

The tableofcontents gives the page number,

but how can I get it to the Question number of the first question in this section?
e.g. like this


The contents of the ToC is written to with every call to \section, which ultimately calls \addcontentsline. This function necessarily writes \thepage, which you can patch to write something else.

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain, twoside]{ctexrep}

\ctexset{
    chapter    =  {
        name   =  {},
        number =  {}
    },            
    section    =  {
        name   =  {},
        number =  {}
    }
}%

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\tcbset{%
  colback          = white,
  colframe         = black,
  title filled     = false,
  bookmark         = {Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
\NewTColorBox[
  auto counter,
  number freestyle = { Q\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter} }
  ]{question}{ O{}mo }{
  fonttitle        = \bfseries,
  title            = \thetcbcounter:,
  #1
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\mytopic}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \begin{question}{Question label}
    #1  
  \end{question}
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Patch \addcontentsline to insert question number rather than \thepage
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}% <cmd>
  {\thepage}% <search>
  {Q\inteval{\value{tcb@cnt@question}+1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{First}
\mytopic{\lipsum[1]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[2]}

\clearpage
\section{Second}
\mytopic{\lipsum[3]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[4]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[5]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[6]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[7]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[8]}

\clearpage
\section{Third}
\mytopic{\lipsum[9]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[10]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[11]}
\mytopic{\lipsum[12]}

\end{document}

In the above example, \thepage was replaced (using a patch thanks to etoolbox) with Q\inteval{\value{tcb@cnt@question}+1}. Note that the tcolorbox counter associated with each question is only stepped at the time it's called. So, since \section is called prior to setting the first question of that section, the correct question counter is obtained via \inteval{<cntr>+1}.
